# button not moving depending on content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap carousel and button that I used in my site 
[image]

I want the button not moving depending on the content. How can I do it without moving regarding the content of the carousel?

This is my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid hookup-wrap">

        <div class="container">

            <!-- main slider carousel -->
            <div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <div class="col-md-12 m-t50" id="slider">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                                <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="active item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" data-slide-number="0">
                                        <p>
                                            Sign up for a free account to get started. Your kinectAPI.com account creates dedicated space for your sensor data and applications on Windows Azure™. Within your account, you can define your applications, register your Kinect™ sensors, download the Local Client, and monitor the usage of data being created and accessed by your applications.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" data-slide-number="1">
                                        <p>
                                            There’s a lot of raw data that is generated by the sensor, which is why kinectAPI pre-processes the raw data stream so that only what your application needs is uploaded to the cloud. You define what data in the raw stream your app needs in your kinectAPI account, either from selecting individual modules or by selecting from our pre-cooked definitions (e.g. “I need to detect Presence). This way, when your Local Client syncs with your kinectAPI account, the parts of the stream you need are uploaded for cloud access, and the rest is ignored.
                                        </p>    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" data-slide-number="2">
                                        <p>
                                            The Local Client is a native Windows application running on the Appliance - which is what we call the PC that your sensor is connected to. The Local Client is logged into your kinectAPI account, and automatically reads what applications you have defined. From there, you simply select the app that you need the data for, and the Appliance starts to capture the appropriate data and send it to the cloud ready for it to be accessed via our API and consumed by your application. 
                                        </p>                              
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" data-slide-number="3">
                                        <p>
                                            Once your Local Client is sending data to the cloud, accessing that data is as simple as writing RESTful API calls from your application.
                                        </p>    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" data-slide-number="4">
                                        <p>
                                            It’s free to create your kinectAPI account! You’ll be given a basic level of cloud storage and API call limits to begin building your first application using kinectAPI, during which you’ll no doubt discover how easy it is to use. Once your application starts to push the quotas of your free account, you can easily upgrade to one of the paid options that will be available, giving you greater cloud storage and API call limits. If you’re building something BIG, you can always contact us and we can customise a package that meets your needs.
                                        </p>    
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <!-- main slider carousel nav controls --> 
                                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>

                                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!--/main slider carousel-->


        </div>

        <div class="container">
                    <div class="row text-center  p-t30 hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">

                        <button type="submit " class="btn btn-green btn-lg-custom"  data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>  Request Access to Private Beta</button>

                    </div>
        </div>

    </div
```

Comment: try using absolute position to your button class

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer but I already resolved it now. putting a height solved my problem :)